# Java -- Multiple classes

Tags: java, class, methods

So for my course programming with java I want to exercise a bit. I made a project about planets. I got 4 planets with each of them contain information. I made a "constructor" class Planet:

```
public class Planet {

    String name;
    int number;
    String color;
    int width;


    public Planet(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void Number(int Number){
        number =  Number;
    }

    public void Color(String Color){
        color = Color;
    }

    public void Width(int Width){
        width = Width;
    }

    public void printPlanet(){
        System.out.println("Name:"+ name );
        System.out.println("Number:" + number );
        System.out.println("Color:" + color );
        System.out.println("Width:" + width);
    }
}
```

and other classes (total = 4) of this type that represent the planets:

```
public class Earth {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Planet earth = new Planet("Earth");

        earth.Number(2);
        earth.Color("Blue");
        earth.Width(47000);

    }
}
```

But now i want to create a simple file with simple code that outputs all the information of all the planets together. I know I can put all the codes from the planets files in one but it's too much and I want a simple file that contains one or two methods/constructors that outputs all the information. Thanks

Comment: You can't "create" information and have less constructors than there are planets to talk about. You _can_, however, create some `static` instances of `Planet` inside of `Planet` (yes you can do that) and just have all the existing planets saved there. (i.e. `static Planet Mercury`,`static Planet Venus`, etc). Then just access those.

Comment: You can creat a static Arraylist member in the class that the constructor will use to store the each created instance. Then you can have a static method that will itterate the Arraylist and call the printPlanet for each record.

Comment: Ok I get it but what statement should be under those 'static' instances in order to use them in the the new file?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/301570/java-multiple-classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you need to initiate the instances of the planets. In your code it goes something like this (with use of the above given and update class):

```
public class TestPlanets {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        Planet earth = new Planet("Earth", 2, "Blue", 47000);
        Planet pluto = new Planet("Pluto", 9, "Blue", 47000);
        Planet mars = new Planet("Mars", 5, "Blue", 47000);
        Planet venus = new Planet("Venus", 1, "Blue", 47000);

        // make an list of the planets: (called planets)
        ArrayList<Planet> planets = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planets.add(earth);
        planets.add(pluto);
        planets.add(mars);
        planets.add(venus);

        // and now magic:
        for (int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(planets.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I hope you get how this works ;) Java docs and tutorials are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Do the changes to the Planet class as suggested

```
public class Planet {

    private String name;
    private int number;
    private String color;
    private int width;

    public Planet(String name, int number, String color, int width) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.color = color;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void Number(int Number) {
        number = Number;
    }

    public void Color(String Color) {
        color = Color;
    }

    public void Width(int Width) {
        width = Width;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Planet [name=" + name + ", number=" + number + ", color="
                + color + ", width=" + width + "]";
    }

}
```

And for the initialization part

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Planet earth = new Planet("Earth", 2, "Blue", 47000);
    Planet pluto = new Planet("Pluto", 9, "Blue", 47000);
    Planet mars = new Planet("Mars", 5, "Blue", 47000);
    Planet other = new Planet("Other", 1, "Blue", 47000);
    System.out.println(earth);
    System.out.println(pluto);
    System.out.println(mars);
    System.out.println(other);
}
```

Comment: mmm, pluto is not a planet anymore ;(

Comment: Sad:(, but u can choose other one.

Comment: Yeah it's quite nice but is there a way i could do it like this: one file(Planet) that contains the variables and the print-method, 5 files(ex. earth) that contain the information about the variables and executes the print-method and one files that ONLY executes the print-method with the information of all the planets?

Comment: Well, if you suggest to change the `Planet` class, then please also fix the names of the methods and their parameters (see [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)). And you don't need to call `super()`. Btw: the mars isn't "blue" :P.

Comment: Yes you can have one class that would contain list of planets and other main class which would load this list of planets and print it one by one